# Howto validate Collections in Maps

Tags: java, validation, hibernate-validator

I have a problem with the `@Valid` annotation of JSR-303. The [annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e425) works fine for normal lists or and sets, but I am trying to validate Maps which contain Lists, i.e.

```
@Valid
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object1>> map;
```

In this case, instances of `Object1` class are not validated. Is there a convenient way to do this recursively, without iterating over every object and validating it manually?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The specification does not specify the validation behavior when the map values are themselves lists.

From [JSR 303 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/bean_validation-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/):

> Each object provided by the iterator is validated. For Map, the value
>   of each Map.Entry is validated (the key is not validated).

Since the value in your case is a list, which does not have a @Valid annotation, it does not get processed. To get around this you can either:

Wrap the contained list in another bean, forcing the annotation processing onto the list.

```
public class ListHolder<T extends Iterable> {
    @Valid
    public T wrappedList;
}
```

Or alternatively you can write a [custom validator](http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com/2009/02/getting-started-with-jsr-303-bean.html) to handle your complex maps. Something like this:

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidMapValidator.class)
public @interface ValidMap {
   String message() default "valid.map";

   Class<?>[] groups() default {};

   Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

public class ValidMapValidator implements
      ConstraintValidator<ValidMap, Map<?, ?>> {

   @Override
   public void initialize(final ValidMap annotation) {
      return;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isValid(final Map<?, ?> map,
         final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
      if (map == null || map.size() == 0)
         return true;

      // Iterate each map entry and validate
      return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried to write a custom validator, but to valiate the actual object I need to know the type. Set<ConstraintViolation<Car>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(car);

Comment: You can use wildcards for the generic type. See edits to my answer for an example on how to setup your validator.