# typeMismatch error, even with typeMismatch=msg in messages.properties

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm still having a fatal error instead of a normal form validation when I try to type a `String` in an `int` field of my jsp form. I've added `typeMismatch=msg` in messages.properties ([Howto validate Collections in Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722660/howto-validate-collections-in-maps)) but it didn't work. What else could I be missing?

Comment: Spring MVC application often uses two contexts: ApplicationContext and Dispatcher Servlet Context. Check that `messages.properties` defined in Dispatcher Servlet Context and used by him.

Comment: Thanks for replying. My `messages.properties` is actually `messages_fr.properties` and works fine for many other messages included validation messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem : you can't write this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addSomething", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addSomething(
        @ModelAttribute("something") Something something, 
        @Valid Something validSomething,
        BindingResult result,
        ModelMap map) {
    ...
```

Some attributes had to be converted from String to int and the conversion was made before validation. This is not good! And also `validSomething` is useless. This has fixed the problem :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addSomething", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addSomething(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("something") Something something, 
            BindingResult result,
            ModelMap map) {
        ...
```

That also proves that you better put your code in the question. And by "you" I mean me.