# How to display custom error message for @Valid in non-primitive datatype

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am doing a spring MVC project and I wanted to display an error to the front page if value for employeelist is not selected
Here is my domain class

```
@Valid
private HashMap<Long, String> employeelist = new HashMap<Long, String>();
```

I have Controller, jsp page and also .properties file in place. All my error messages are being displayed except this. Help!!!

Comment: the answer here might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722660/howto-validate-collections-in-maps

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `employeeList` is part of another object, you can use the `Hibernate-Validator` `@NotEmpty` annotation. For example:

**Your object**

```
public class YourObject {

    @NotEmpty(message = "Must specify at least one employee")
    private HashMap<Long, String> employeelist = new HashMap<Long, String>();
}
```

**Your controller**

```
@Controller
public class YourController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void save(@Valid YourObject yourObject) {
        // use your object here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you the problem was I needed a custom validation in place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom JSR-303 validator and like in [this tutorial](http://goldenpackagebyanuj.blogspot.ru/2013/05/custom-jsr-303-validation-using-constraintValidator.html) and there you can define your own validation message.